# Is it possible to run a command after every gem install?

Tags: rubygems, hook

Is there a way to hook commands after every gem install on your system?

I understand there is a Gem#post_install hook but if I'm not wrong its only runs for a specific gem and not globally.

Answer (score 0):

How about a shell function?

*UNTESTED*

```
function install_gem() { gem install "$@" && ruby ./your_script.rb; }
```